# Show text in image box (before image is shown)

Tags: html, css, hover, position, center

Fiddle URL:  https://jsfiddle.net/e8h0jb4a/1/.

```html
    <article><span>1</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
    <article><span>2</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
    <article><span>3</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
    <article><span>4</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
    <article><span>5</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
    <article><span>6</span><img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg"></article>
```

```css
    html{
        font-size: 18pt;
    }
    body{
        background-color: black;
        font-family: "PT Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: 20pt;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        margin: 0.8rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        gap: 0.5rem;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    article{
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #202020;
        border-width: 1.5pt;
        padding: 0;
        width: 9.5rem;
        height: 7.5rem;
        background-color: #101010;
        transition: 202ms;
    
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
        font-size: 50pt;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    img{
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 202ms;
    }
    article:hover{
        background-color: #1f1f1f;
    }
    .open{
        cursor: default;
    }
    .open span{
        display: none;
    }
    .open img{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .open:hover{
        transform: scale(1.8);
    }
```

```js
    $('article').click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('open');
    });
```

You see that each card has some text on it. Once you click a card an image is shown and the text disappears. So far so good. Now I want to get the text vertically centered in each box. And I want the box which you can click for the image to be shown just the visibile box (at the moment you can click below too because of the text which takes up space).

I tried to solve this with absolute position of the text. The problem then is that the animation when you hover images brings the images below the other boxes.

How would you solve the problems? I'm looking for css only changes. Is there even a nice way with my html code or does the html code need to changed as well?

Comment: So you want to align text vertically in the center. And also to show only those images on which user clicks and hide the other ones.

Comment: @PrateekChaubey Correct. And I want to boxes them self to be clickable to show the images. Not the space below (which happens when I add a margin or padding to the span).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flexbox. You can use the `align-items: center` property to vertically align your text, and `justify-content: center` to horizontally align your text. You could also use `text-align: center` for this. Don't forget to set `display: flex`, otherwise, Flexbox will not be used.

[This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) website is very useful for understanding Flexbox.

Comment: Tricky with 2 items inside the article.

Answer (score 0):

So for aligning text vertically center you can use CSS property.

```css
article{
   line-height:7.5rem; //value same as the height
}
```

And for hiding the image when user clicks on different element

```js
$('article').click(function() {
for(var i=0;i<$("article").length;i++){
$("article").eq(i).children().eq(0).css("display","block");
$("article").eq(i).children().eq(1).css("opacity","0");
}

$(this).children().eq(0).css("display","none");
$(this).children().eq(1).css("opacity","1");
});
```

Instead of adding a class you can use this method.

**Edit**

You were able to click beneath the `article` because there was `image` with `opacity:0;` so to fix this problem you can use `display:none;` 
Here is the code

```css
img{
    display: none;
}
.open img{
display:block;
}
```

And you can use the default JS code i.e

```js
 $('article').click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('open');
    });
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vrf58L4s/5/

Comment: So there is no reasonable css only solution?

Comment: Are you sure about that JS code? Do you want to go through all articles when one article is clicked?

Comment: There is solution for CSS but if it will only work on hover not on click

Comment: For changing all the `img` tags to there original position we have to go through all the `article` and set them to the original position.

Comment: But we want to "open" only the article we click.

Comment: yeah that is what the above code does, it closes the article which is not clicked and opens the clicked ones.

Comment: I just tried it out (https://jsfiddle.net/bx19k837/) and it has a few problems: The first problem is the one which I already mentioned: You can click underneath the box to open it. Further problems: The hover effect on opened images doesn't work anymore. The hover effect on boxes works wrong (you can be underneath it). I don't want boxes the close when you open another one (this I was already confused about in the above comments).

Comment: You should be clear that what you want to achieve , even now your comment have some problems i.e what do you mean by `you can be underneath it` then also I have edited the answer you can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232983/discussion-between-prateek-chaubey-and-principal-ideal-domain).

Comment: Thanks for your current version. This looks much better, but there is still a problem I couldn't fix myself: There is no fade in effect on opened pictures anymore. I tried to get it back using serveral different classes where the first class brings the image back setting "display: block" and the next brings the opacity from 0 to 1 but no transitions are shown anymore. I don't understand it. How to fix that?

Comment: You mean the transition effect . And also upvote and accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I will upvote your answer if it fully works. But the transition is still an missing aspect.

Comment: First of all learn how to ask a good question and  also don't confuse everyone with your comment that what you want to achieve.

Comment: And I have given the answers that you have asked in question

Comment: Well, when you look at the code in my question then you see that there the transition was already included and it worked (increase the transition time to really see that the fade effect worked in my original question). Of course I don't want the stuff which already works to get destroyed by the answer. So you havn't given the answer to my question so far.